# How to check if google cloud function responsible for SSR runs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have some code responsible for SSR:

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import express from 'express';
import fs from 'fs';
import App from './app/containers/App';

const app = express();

app.get('**', (req, res) => {
  const html = renderToString(<App />);
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=600, s-maxage=1200');
  res.send(html);
});

export const ssrapp = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

And it should of course fail. I mean - it should just show plain html text from `App` when entering my app hosted on firebase. However - it doesn't happen. My app just loads as it used to (it shows everything - not just the html text).

**My question**: How to check if that `ssrapp` google cloud function even runs? I tried to use some `console.log` inside it, however no logs are visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase console will show log messages for each function invocation, regardless if you logged anything with `console.log()`.  If you see nothing in the log, then your function is not running (or the console is temporarily broken).